# Elo ratings: how many votes must be cast to get a reliable outcome?

Tags: system, rating

I want to setup a system that will end up ranking competitors against one another based on the votes. In this example, there will be 250 competitors, but only 4 people able to cast votes. We ideally want it setup in a hot-or-not fashion (using the Elo rating system), but I wonder how many votes must be cast before we'd get a fair ranking?

Does anyone have any thoughts on how I might establish a fair(ish) rating without each voter casting thousands of votes?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: There are plenty of questions on SO about Elo ratings

Comment: There are plenty of off-topic questions on SO, that doesn't change the fact that your question is off-topic as well. The tour explicitly states that "Anything not directly related to writing computer programs" is off-topic; your question more than fits this description. It might be on topic on programmers.SE, but I'm not too sure of that as I don't frequent that site...

Comment: enhancements like Glicko include a metric of how accurate the rating is ("ratings deviation"), so you can just wait until that gets within some tolerance.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your k-factor, i.e. how quickly you want ratings to correct to changes in skill.

If you use a higher k-factor, the rankings will quickly approximate the skill of competitors. However, in that case the ranking will be mostly a short term value, with chance, pairings and "bad days" affecting it greatly.

Using a multiple level k-factor system, like the chess world does, lets you both quickly converge to approximate ratings for new players (and the initial set of players) and track a longer term ranking for established players.

I would recommend starting with the values FIDE uses, so you don't have to retest extensively:

- 400 as a denominator in the exponents, so that 200 points' difference = 75% winning chance
- k = 30 for the first 30 games
- k = 20 after that until the player has reached 2400 ranking at least once
- k = 10 thereafter

If 30 games is too much for the initial period, you could use a lower number but increase the initial k proportionally. Beware that this will make the initial ranking very variable.

If you want a different normalization than the 200 points -> 75%, you can divide all the numbers above by the same constant.